# How to show in template current users role in project?

Tags: python, html, django, python-3.x, django-1.10

Can someone say where I did mistake?

I have `Project` model. Every project has members. I have `project_detail` page where I want to show current user's username and his role in project. Right know in template it shows me only current user's username but not his role in project.

**models.py:**

```
class Project(models.Model):
    members = models.ManyToManyField(User, through='Member', help_text=_('Members'))

ROLE_CHOICES = (
    ('manager', _('Manager')),
    ('developer', _('Developer')),
    ('business_analyst', _('Business Analyst')),
    ('system_analyst', _('System Analyst')),
)

class Member(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    role = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=ROLE_CHOICES)
```

**views.py:**

```
def project_detail(request, project_code):
    project = get_object_or_404(Project, pk=project_code, status='open')
    context = {'project': project,}
    return render(request, 'project/project_detail.html', context)
```

**project_detail.html:**

```
<span class="nav-link active navbar-text">
   {{ user.get_username }}:

   {% for member in project.member_set.all %}
       {% if member.user == user.get_username %}
          {{ member.get_role_display }}
       {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</span>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you comparing the user against the result of `get_username`? That presumably returns a username string, but the user is, well, a user. This would work:

```
{% if member.user == user %}
  {{ member.get_role_display }}
{% endif %}
```

But don't do this. It's very inefficient to loop over all project members and get the user for each one. Instead, do a single query in the view:

```
member = project.member_set.get(user=request.user)
context = {'project': project, 'role': member.get_role_display()}
```

Comment: Thank you for this detail answer!

Comment: Can I ask one more question in template? What I need to use in template? I mean just call this: `{{role}}`?

Comment: Sorry, meant to call the `get_role_display()` method in the view. But yes, just do `role` in the template.

Comment: I have error: `AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'get_role_display'` in this line: `'role': member.get_role_display()` Do you have any ideas why it raise this error?

Comment: Sorry, my fault again, I should have used `.get()`- updated.